# How Intents work internally?

Tags: android, android-intent

I developed an App and i executed some tests. This tests consists in
sending data from one background service to another background
service.
All data was received when the transmission rate was low (4 intents/second). However when
i increased the transmission rate (8 and 12 intents/second), some data (typically 2- 3 %) was
not received by the destination service.

All intents were broadcasted and the services were running locally.

Can anyone tell me, how the
OS treats the Intents and the whole mechanism works, in order to find
the reason why data was not received by it's receiver ?

Best regards,

Comment: can you post some sample code that you used to test this?

Comment: i just execute sendBroadcast() inside a loop, controlling the rate with Thread.sleep(). I just wanted to see how Intents bahave with high transmission rate. I only used Intents before to start services, activities and so on...

Comment: Without supplying a complete set of sample projects that demonstrates your issue, we have to assume that the problem lies in your code. "how the OS treats the Intents and the whole mechanism works" is an extremely complex topic, probably dozens of pages in length, and may have nothing to do with the actual issue at hand.

Comment: You may have right, but what does the OS do when he can't send an Intent to the broadcastreceiver. Did he put the Intent in a queue or the intent is discarded ? When he queues the intent and the OS receives an new one that match the intent- filter, did the OS deletes the older intent or both are sent to the broadcast receiver ? These are the questions that i'm interested in at this moment. Even when I look to the source code, i can't figure out, which action the OS takes when this occurs.

Comment: watch this link out this might help....
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would rather recommend to bind the service and then using Handlers for IPC. A good example can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html This is a lot faster and more reliable.

On how Intents work internally you can have a look at the source code: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L893

Answer (score 3):

Here are the relevant methods (you can see the first one geting called from the ContextImpl.broadcastIntent() method, see the link in [Force's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203892/375929)):

- [ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent%28android.app.IApplicationThread%2Candroid.content.Intent%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.content.IIntentReceiver%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Candroid.os.Bundle%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29)
- which in turn calls [ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked%28com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord,java.lang.String,android.content.Intent,java.lang.String,android.content.IIntentReceiver,int,java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,int,int%29)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>One possible reason is that Android inter-process communication is synchronous. The calling client process is blocked for the duration of the answer of the server process. Your Service with the timer is blocked for (very small) periods of time, which could result in the behaviour you observed.</strike>

Source: [Android Binder - Android Interprocess Communication by Thorsten Schreiber](http://www.nds.rub.de/media/attachments/files/2012/03/binder.pdf), p 11 - 13.

**EDIT**: I've kept the answer published because Chris Stratton's and  João Nunes's comments are valuable.

Comment: Actually the "calling client process" is not blocked.  There's an important distinction between activity/service, process, and thread.  While the thread calling a particular API may well block, other threads of the process are *not* blocked, as long as the process exists and they are not (by their own choice) waiting for the return of blocking system calls (either directly, or by having called platform APIs which ultimately are).

Comment: When we send intents using sendBroadcast() method, there are asynchronous - at least is that that is written at android developers. But your answer might get me another opinion how the whole implementation works. Could it be that the broadcast receiver is busy and the OS discards intents because they can't be sent to the correspondent broadcast receiver ?

Comment: @Chris Stratton thanks for clarification. My understanding was that IPC between different processes was synchronous, based on the source I linked to, while your comment refers to different threads (and not necessarily different processes). So if the services are in different processes, communication would be synchronous, but if they are in different threads in the same process communication is asynchronous. Appreciate your perspective on this.

Comment: IPC may well be synchronous for the thread which does it (execution can effectively transfer from the calling thread to the called thread and then back), but it does not directly effect the execution of other threads in the calling process.